# Inverse kinematic joint limits

Tags: c++, rotation

I want to limit the joint angle of my character.
I have just one issue i can't get the value of the joint limits of the human 
-i search about max, min angle of each joint in x and y but i can't get them-
can someone give me them.

Comment: I Can't give you the exact values, because they vary from person to person. My recommendation is that you play around with each joint and see what works for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about human physiology, not game specific expertise. [You can search out resources in medicine, physiotherapy, and human factors to answer this question](https://www.verywellhealth.com/what-is-normal-range-of-motion-in-a-joint-3120361).

Answer (score 1):

## How do I implement joint limits?

I usually implement joint limits with a simple if-statement. For example, this would work for revolute joints.

```
if (limb.rotation >  45.0f) limb.rotation =  45.0f;
if (limb.rotation < -45.0f) limb.rotation = -45.0f;
```

This works with Jacobian Methods, CCD Methods, or FABRIK Methods.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about implementation, but learning the relevant values to limit to. e.g. how far will a human foot bend upward.

Comment: I would use 30deg and 180deg